# Websocket data to update ChartJs chart

Tags: javascript, charts, websocket

I'm trying to update a chart by using data returned from a Websocket, however there are no errors the chart is not being drawn.

```
var chartData = {
  labels: [], // currently empty will contain all the labels for the data points
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Time",
      fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
      pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data: [] // currently empty will contain all the data points for bills
    }
  ]
};


var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(chartData);

websocket = new WebSocket("wss url");


websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { 

    var pjson = jQuery.parseJSON(evt.data);
    console.log(pjson);

    return(pjson);
    var sec_left = pjson.somedata;
    var now_str = pjson.somedata;

    if(now_str)
    {
       chartData.labels.push(somedata); 
    }
    if(sec_left)
    {
       chartData.datasets[0].data.push(somedata);
    }

};
```

However this does not draw the chart, but when I add

```
var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(chartData);
```

to within the websocket.onmessage function the chart is being drawn but the whole chart is redrawn again not that the chart is updated with new addition of data. How can I fix it so that the chart is updated not completely redrawn from each request from the websocket?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `update()` method to redraw your chart. From the docs on [Line Chart Methods](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-prototype-methods):

> Calling `update()` on your Chart instance will re-render the chart with any updated values, allowing you to edit the value of multiple existing points, then render those in one animated render loop.
>
> ```
> myLineChart.datasets[0].points[2].value = 50;
> // Would update the first dataset's value of 'March' to be 50
> myLineChart.update();
> // Calling update now animates the position of March from 90 to 50.
> ```